# Login + TabHost

Tags: java, android, authentication

The doubt is this , I have a Login screen, and so user correctly enter the fields, a new page with a TabHost should be displayed , but simply everything I 've tried so far not given any results

```
//Login Class

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText user;
    private EditText passaword;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login_layout);
        user = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.user);
        passaword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);

    }
    public void entrarOnClick(View v) {
        String usuarioInformado = user.getText().toString();
        String senhaInformada = passaword.getText().toString();

        if("a".equals(usuarioInformado) &&
                "a".equals(senhaInformada)) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,TabsActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            //startActivity(new Intent(this,TabsActivity.class));
        } else {
            String mensagemErro = getString(R.string.erro_autenticacao);
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this,mensagemErro,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the class that has the layout of tabs , you should call the classes for each Tab

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class TabsActivity extends TabActivity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState ){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tab_layout);
        TabHost tabHost =(TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        TabHost.TabSpec tab1 = tabHost.newTabSpec("ABA UM");
        tab1.setIndicator("TAB1");            tab1.setIndicator("",getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
        tab1.setContent(new Intent(this,ProfileTabActivity.class));
        tabHost.addTab(tab1);
    }
}
```

Comment: what error you are getting can you print the logcat?

Answer (score 0):

You should use TabLayout of the android design support library. Check out point 4 of http://hmkcode.com/material-design-app-android-design-support-library-appcompat/